# Is this superfluous PHP mysqli_real_escape_string() with regex

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `php` script that takes user input and inserts it into a MySQL database. I want to achieve a couple of things with the insert script, a) make sure only acceptable characters get captured and b) prevent `SQL` injection.

I have a form element like so:

```
<input class="form-control" id="mrn" name="mrn" type="text" maxlength="17">
```

I then have in the `php` script the following:

```
// Gather the posted data into local variables
$mrn_demographics = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect,preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $_POST['mrn']));

// Form data error handling
if($mrn_demographics == "" ){
echo "The form submission is missing data.";   
} else {
// End form data error handling
$sql = "INSERT INTO nys_demographics (
    mrn
)
VALUES('$mrn_demographics')";
}
```

Does this achieve the ability to prevent `SQL` injection and is the use of the `mysqli_real_escape_string` superfluous since I am also using the `regex` in order to capture what I  want, which is alpha-numeric characters.

Comment: Nope, always `mysqli_real_escape_string()` anyways, it can't hurt. And in actuality, you should make your queries using prepared statements.

Comment: Forget `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, use [prepared statements](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) with bound parameters.

Comment: @EvanCarslake Are you saying it *needs* to be escaped, or it's a good idea to escape it anyway?

Comment: Saying it *needs* to be escaped isn't the right way to word it, a better way to say it would be that it is beyond a great idea to do so. Use prepared statements anyways.

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is **not** sufficient to prevent SQL injection. Filtering to a known subset of values is good, but using bound parameters is your only real choice.

Comment: Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2864740 (Some implementations may choose to "escape"; regardless, using placeholders is THE way to write 99% of SQL text queries and is proven effective to mitigate first-order attacks. Talking about other methods most of the time - such as now - is a boring tangent to a solved problem.)

Comment: Also, *validation* should **not** be confused with SQL injection safety. Validation is to ensure a business rule is met. SQL injection mitigation is to ensure that SQL will save the expected data - ie. quotes, or whatever - and not allow SQL injection for *any* input data, regardless of what business rules/filters may previously have (been thought to have) been applied. A correctly written program will do *both* business validation and apply the proper use of SQL - consistently.

Comment: Regex and escaping data are two different animals and should be inside separate cages. If and when you plan on using this as a register/login system or it's already that, and that you are using a safe hashing method, escaping passwords will do more harm than good; *believe me*.

Comment: Since no real answer can come of this and could even be opinion-based, am voting to close the question as too broad. It could also fall as unclear and a possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I see that there is a question of, is this question duplicative, I have seen the question and answer referenced, I don't think this is a duplicate, since I am, in part after, is `mysqli_real_escape_string()` synonymous to the regex expression, given some think the question too broad, I suppose closing might be necessary but not altogether certain. If the general consensus is to close because of the referenced question and breadth then I'll accept the duplicate closure.